Can't find a way to add separate and add elements to a list in Python
Im trying to make a code that reads each element in a list, separates the duplicate ones and adds a special character before printing
Exemple:
15 16 17 17 17 18 19
15 16 BB 17 18 19


Already solved the separating part but I cant add the character in the list since it prints the entire thing. So far I've wrote this down
sequen=[22, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 25]
compar=[]
reser=[]
for chk in sequen:
    if chk not in compar:
        compar.append(chk)
    else:
        reser.append(chk)
    for i in reser:
        if i!=reser[1]:
            reser.append("RP")
        elif i==reser[1]:
            reser.pop(0)
        print(reser)


Your question would be more clear if you showed actual vs. expected results.  Also, don’t modify the item you’re iterating over.

You might want to use sets instead of lists. When you  do chk not in compar you are traversing the whole list looking for that element. Although with such small list this is not a problem, the way to go is using a set.

l = [15, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 19]

unique = list(set(l)) # remove duplicate values

# repeat-list using if the count is more than 1
repeated = [x for x in l if l.count(x) > 1] 

repeated = list(set(repeated)) # remove duplicate values
L = len(unique)
i = 0
while i < L:
    x = unique[i]
    if x in repeated:
        unique.insert(i, 'RP')
        L = L + 1
        i = i + 1
    i = i + 1
    
print(unique) # Output : [15, 16, 'RP', 17, 18, 19]

